# Define an alias to access classes in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this class in the file `Models.ts`:

```
module App.Shared.Models {
    export class UserModel
    {
        public Id: number;
        public Name: string;
        public Email: string;
    }
}
```

It is ugly creating a new instance of this class: `let user = new App.Shared.Models.UserModel;`. I'de like to create an alias, but I'm not figuring out how to do it so I can have `let user = new Models.UserModel;`.

Searching for similar topics here, I tried

```
import Models = App.Shared.Models;
let user = new Models.UserModel;
```

This code gives me no warning and compiles, but when I run, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Models')
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want

```
const Models = App.Shared.Models;
```

(at least it works in the playground in a single file).

Maybe

```
import * as Models from "<path-to-models>"
```

would work too, but I am less sure.

Comment: Thanks, but it did't work. I'm using VS2022 and the `Models.ts` file is in the same folder of my `Index.ts` file.